# How to overwrite the duplicate http cache headers in a java based web app?

Tags: java, caching, webpack, browser-cache

We are integrating webpack in our legacy java based webapp. As a first step, added frontend-maven-plugin to install node, npm and webpack. Able to bundle the js and css fine.

I'm also utilizing cache busting in webpack. The bundled js and css are hashed and has a name of format bundle.hash.js. And i wrote a custom tag for jsp to pass the parameter and get the hashed file. This all seems to be working fine, now the idea is to set a long cache of an year on the bundled files.

I wrote a custom filter which implements javax.servlet.Filter and setting the cache headers. And added this filter for js, css mappings in web.xml

```
int cacheAge = 31536000; // setting long year cache
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age="+ cacheAge);
```

The problem is when i run the app for the bundle.hash.js file there are 2 cache-controls getting set. As a result the bundle.*.js file is not getting cached. For the bundle.hash.css just the max-age of 31536000 is getting set as expected and it is getting cached by the browser.

```
cache-control: max-age=31536000
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

I'm not able to figure out how and from where is the no-cache, max-age=0 getting set for the js files. I wonder node/webpack is setting it under the hood? If so, how can i override it in the servlet Filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out after spending few hours. Spring security was adding the no-cache, max-age=0 header eventhough i had set max-age in the servlet filter. I set the security to none in the context.xml file for the bundle files under dist dir and seems to be working fine.